# Is there a "better" way to do an online check with retry logic with anti-flapping? (Python)

Tags: python, logic

I've got a network device that doesn't hold its WiFi connection brilliantly and occasionally drops off the network completely. Although there are dedicated network monitoring tools out there, I thought it would be a nice exercise to write a small monitoring script in Python.

I want to check the status of the device once per minute with an ICMP echo. Because the network connection is a little unreliable, I'll ignore short drop-outs and so will try up to three times to get a positive response.

Additionally, because the device can sometimes reboot, I want to ignore outages of up to two or three minutes. Once the device has missed three checks, I'll send a message to myself saying it's offline. Similarly, once it has been back online for three checks I'll send a message saying it's back online.

The following code is a test of the logic I came up with; I've applied this to the actual script and it does seem to do the job. However, it seems clunky and I'm sure there's some clever Pythonic way of doing things that I haven't thought of. Note that I'm posting this rather than the full script since this can be executed standalone and doesn't have any real network dependencies.

How can I improve this code so that it's more compact and Pythonic? Thanks!

```
"""Test ping logic"""
import time


def ping_device(iter_count):
    """Fake ping device function"""

    # Pretend that this function tries up to three times to get a good ping response :)

    if iter_count == 5:
        response = False
    elif 11 <= iter_count <= 14:
        response = False
    else:
        response = True

    return response


def main():
    """Main functions"""
    previous_status = True
    current_status_count = 0
    adjusted_status = True
    previous_adjusted = True
    iteration_counter = 0

    while True:
        iteration_counter += 1
        print(f"Pinging iteration {iteration_counter}... ", end="")

        status = ping_device(iteration_counter)
        if status:
            print("OK")
        else:
            print("FAIL")

        if status != previous_status:
            current_status_count = 0
            previous_status = status
        else:
            current_status_count += 1

        if current_status_count > 2:
            adjusted_status = status

        if adjusted_status != previous_adjusted:
            previous_adjusted = adjusted_status
            if status:
                print("***** Device is online *****")
            else:
                print("!!!!! Device is offline !!!!!")

        print(f"---> Current status count is {current_status_count}")

        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In the actual monitoring script, the ping/retry logic looks like this:

```
        for attempt in range(RETRIES + 1):
            ping_response = ping(MONITOR_HOST)
            if status is None:
                if ping_response:
                    status = True
                    previous_status = True
                    adjusted_status = True
                    previous_adjusted = True
                    send_telegram("Current status is online.")
                    break
                else:
                    status = False
                    previous_status = False
                    adjusted_status = False
                    previous_adjusted = False
                    send_telegram("Current status is offline.")
            else:
                if ping_response:
                    status = True
                    break
                else:
                    status = False
```

As well as doing the retries, this handles sending an initial message telling me if the device is online or offline when monitoring is started (status is None on start). Note that I use 'attempt' rather than '_' in the loop as I do log the attempt number.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at some exponential backoff retry algorithms? E.G., https://keestalkstech.com/2021/03/python-utility-function-retry-with-exponential-backoff/

Comment: You seem to be asking for a code review, which there is a sibling site to do : [Stack Exchange's Code Review website](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) ;)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Wasn't aware of the code review site -- will take a look, cheers!